# Random X variable data table R

Tags: r, data.table, read.csv

When I read in a .csv I previously wrote out, there are random and undesired "X" and "X.1" variables. How do I avoid this?

I am writing the csv as such

```
write.csv(bind.data,paste("bind.data.same.rm",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep=""))
```

And reading it later:

```
bind.data <- data.table(read.csv("bind.data.same.rm2015-02-28.csv"))
```

Comment: Add `, row.names = FALSE` to your `write.csv`

Comment: Why don't you use `fread()` to directly read in as `data.table`?